# Splash background in splash.xml not showing in Activity SplashScreen.java

Tags: android

I was trying to show a splash/welcome screen while my app is loading image data, the data load alright but the background image in splash.xml just won't show, I am posting my codes below.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

 private ChannelDB mDB;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
    AppConnect.getInstance(this);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
               if (tabIsExist(null)==true){
                mDB.Reset();

                   Bitmap bigbang1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigbang1);
                   Bitmap bigbang2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigbang2);
                   Bitmap bigbang3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigbang3);
                   Bitmap bigbang4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigbang4);


                   mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(bigbang1, "生活大爆炸（第一季）" ,"http://appkon.com/hdtvs/channel/bigbang1.xml"  ,"http://movie.douban.com/subject/5372374/" ));
                   mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(bigbang2, "生活大爆炸（第二季）" ,"http://appkon.com/hdtvs/channel/bigbang2.xml"  ,"http://movie.douban.com/subject/3190880/" ));
                   mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(bigbang3, "生活大爆炸（第三季）" ,"http://appkon.com/hdtvs/channel/bigbang3.xml"  ,"http://movie.douban.com/subject/3990470/" ));
                   mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(bigbang4, "生活大爆炸（第四季）" ,"http://appkon.com/hdtvs/channel/bigbang4.xml"  ,"http://movie.douban.com/subject/4804079/" ));

                   }
               }catch (Exception e) {


                       Intent i = new Intent();
                       i.setClassName("com.appkon.hdtvs",
                                      "com.appkon.hdtvs.HDtvs");
                       finish();
                       startActivity(i);
                   }
                finally {

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClassName("com.appkon.hdtvs",
                            "com.appkon.hdtvs.HDtvs");
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }

           }

     };
     splashThread.start();
}

    public boolean tabIsExist(String channelS_TABLE){
        boolean result = false;
        if(channelS_TABLE == null){
                return false;
        }
        Cursor cursor= ChannelDB.check();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        try {
                if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
                        if(count>0){
                                result = true;
                        }
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.toString(),"error:"+e.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,HDtvs.class);  
            startActivity(intent);  
            this.finish(); 
        }                
        return result;
    }


}
```

and this is my splash.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Async Task class,makes it easier..

Comment: Agree with sony, use AsyncTask and put your data load code into doInBackground. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

See a better way to make splash screen [simple](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html)
and [advanced](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSplash.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

first post xD hope this helps.

You need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml to include your splash activity

```
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Remember to set category to `LAUNCHER`, and your main activity should look like this

```
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.anibalismo.sovica.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Don´t forget to change the main´s category to DEFAULT and alse change Main action name to `"com.anibalismo.sovica.MAIN"`... think you should use your package name there, but not obligatory.

Source: [Youtube: thenewboston](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5uJeno3xg8&list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8&index=13&feature=plpp_video)